# openseadragon crops a very wide image?

Tags: openseadragon

I have the following simple code for showing a sequence of svgs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="openseadragon1" style="width: 1500px; height: 1000px;"></div>
<script src="openseadragon.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
        id: "openseadragon1",
        prefixUrl: "./images/",
        tileSources: [
        {type: 'image', url: "./img/pc_000.svg", buildPyramid: false},
        {type: 'image', url: "./img/pc_001.svg", buildPyramid: false},
        {type: 'image', url: "./img/pc_002.svg", buildPyramid: false},
        ],
        sequenceMode: true,
        preserveViewport: true,
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The svg dimensions are 332ptx20000pt (short, but extremely wide). When the images are displayed they are cropped horizontally (at about 12000pt approx.), but when I load the images directly in a browser, the browser (Chrome, Edge) shows it in their entirety.

Is there a way to display these wide images uncropped in openseadragon?

[Sample image and code](https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/files/5199672/openseadragon-bug.zip)

Comment: Interesting. Can you share a link to one of the SVG images so I take a look?

Comment: @iangilman I added a link to the code and a sample image at the end of the original post. Thanks!

Comment: I'm terribly sorry I didn't get back to you! The last half of 2020 was kind of crazy for me. I'm now catching up. I've downloaded the sample image and code and have run it on my browser (Mac Chrome) and I believe I'm seeing the entire width of the image in OSD. I'm not sure where that leaves us... are you still having the problem?